# A sequence of polynomials defined by differentiation

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(t)=e^{-1/t}$, $t\gt0$.  Let, for each positive integer $n$, $P_n$ be the polynomial such that $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)= P_n(\frac{1}{t})e^{-1/t}$ for all $t>0$. Show that

$$P_{n+1}(x)= x^2 \left(P_n (x)-\frac{d}{dx} P_n(x)\right)$$

I have found the $n$th order derivative of $f(t)$ which is $P_n$, but can't proceed further.

Comment: What does "suffix" mean?

Comment: u can see the editation made by maisam hedyelloo..

Comment: No, the "suffix" is still there.

Comment: It's obviously $P_n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I thought it might have been, but I wanted to know from the OP before editing.

Comment: I boldly edited the question.  soumajit, please check that it matches your intention.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you very much for editing the question....but can you just say me about how did you do this as it can be useful for me in the future........

Comment: You can see the full edit history (including my changes) by clicking the link under the question that says "edited Jun 9 at 18:38".

Comment: @NateEldredge do you have any software for this editing purpose ??????

Comment: @soumajitdas: I don't use any special software, but the math syntax comes from LaTeX.  You can find a lot more information in the [Math.SE FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @NateEldredge are you in facebook ????? then we cn just stay in touch with other and discuss different problems of mathematics.

Comment: @soumajitdas: No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have solved the problem, and the only difficulties are ones of notation. We have
$$\frac{d^n f}{dt^n}=P_n(1/t)e^{-1/t}.$$
Differentiate. We get, by the Product Rule and Chain Rule,
$$\frac{d^{n+1} f}{dt^{n+1}}=P_n(1/t)\frac{1}{t^2}e^{-1/t}-\frac{1}{t^2}P_n'(1/t)e^{-1/t}.$$
This is equal to 
$$\left(\frac{1}{t^2}P_n(1/t)-\frac{1}{t^2}P_n'(1/t)\right)e^{-1/t}.$$
So by definition, 
$$P_{n+1}(1/t)=\frac{1}{t^2}P_n(1/t)-\frac{1}{t^2}P_n'(1/t).$$
Set $x=1/t$ and we get the desired result.